# React Monorepo yarn workspaces + typescript + absolute imports

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yarnpkg, ts-loader, yarn-workspaces

I'm having issues setting up an React project with yarn workspaces and typescript.
My folder structure is:

```
-root
 -package.json
 -workspaces
  -web
  -common
```

and my `package.json` file is:

```
{
  "name": "my-project-name",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
  "workspaces/web",
  "workspaces/common"
  ],
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
}
```

My issue is: when I import files on `web` from the `common` project, it works fine if it's a `.js` file, but fails with `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` when using `.ts` or `.tsx` files.

Any ideas on what I might be missing?

Comment: Same issue here, I'd love to have an answer!

Comment: 1 year later, still searching for answer

Answer (score 2):

I recommend adopting the following file hierarchy:

```
- root
- package.json
- tsconfig.json
- packages 
  - common
    - package.json
    - tsconfig.json 
- services
  - web
    - package.json
    - tsconfig.json
```

Everything in the `packages` folder can be imported. Services are "leaf" projects that you don't want to import in other projects.

With that as a base, your root package.json should be setup like that:

```json
{
"name": "my-project-name",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages": [
      "packages/*",
      "services/**/*"
    ],
  ],
}
```

Then, you also need to tell typescript how to resolve the imports.

In the root tsconfig.json, set the following:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@myproject/*": ["packages/*/src"]
    },
}
```

Make sure that every tsconfig extends this base with `"extends": "../../tsconfig.json"`

Inside `web/package.json` or any package that needs to import common, define common as a dependency:

```
{
  [...]
  "dependencies": {
    "@myproject/common": "*",
  }
}
```

Now if your common package.json has a name set to `"@myproject/common", you can import your code inside web with :

```js
import { myUtilFunction } from "@myproject/common";
```

I would advise you to also use learn with a setup like this.
You will also need to modify a bit your build pipeline, since you're importing files inside /web that are outside the /web folder. For a more complete example, you can check out this repo: https://github.com/NiGhTTraX/ts-monorepo